# How to retrieve path of currently opened html file in java?

Tags: java, html, url

I want to create a java application which takes screenshot of a html file and save it in the same location where html is located.I was able to capture the screenshot using Robot class but don't know how to store the screenshot in the same path where html file is present.Whenever we open any html file in web browser,we all could see its physical path in the URL section of a browser .Does anyone know of any java class which can be used to retrive it?

**[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qEd2.png)**

Comment: request.getRequestURI() can be used to find the relative path of a request.

Comment: But can it be used to get the path of html file locally stored on your machine?If yes,can you please explain how to do it?

Comment: Can you let me know about the web application yours you are building is it normal servlet based or any framework there.

Comment: It is not a web application.Its a standalone java application.When i open any html file using any browser its actual path can be seen in the URL of a web browser.I want to know how can i retrive it .For eg i open sample.html  file in chrome browser you can see its path like file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/sample.html.I want to know how can i retrieve it using java.Please help.

Comment: Who launches the browser and makes it open the html file?